# if else condition excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Image 1:[This image is for machine number if the machine number In practical results sheet matches the data in machine number in chapter sheet the data has to be copied in the sheet practical results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVGCK.png) 
Image 2:[Machine number in Practical sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxo9d.png)[Should paste here in max score if machine number matches] 
Image 3:[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3iKQ.png)I have a small question related to Excel VBA.

I have 3 sheets in a work book:

- sheet1: Chapters
- sheet2: Mcq results and
- sheet3: Practical results

My question is how to use `if … else` statement in Excel VBA so that I would like to check the machine numbers column in Sheet1 and again cross check the machine number in sheet2 if `sheet1.Machinenumber = Sheet2.Machinenumber` it has to fill all the 12 rows from sheet1 to sheet2 max score column.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
Dim Sht3 As Worksheet
Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
Dim i, j  As Integer
Dim LastBlankRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range


Set Sht3 = Worksheets("Chapters")
Set Sht2 = Worksheets("Practical results")

If (Sht2.Range(E1)) = "M03" Then
Sht3.Range("I2:I13").Copy
Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ElseIf (Sht2.Range(E1)) = "M04" Then
Sht3.Range("J2:J13").Copy
Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```

Second code:

```
Sub Copypaste_Mcq()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Sht3 As Worksheet
Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
Dim i, j  As Integer
Dim LastBlankRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range


Set Sht3 = Worksheets("Chapters")
Set Sht2 = Worksheets("Mcq Results")
'LastRow = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
'LastRow2 = Sht2.Range("G" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
'NumRows = Sht2.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
'Sht2.Activate


'LastBlankRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 LastRow = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
Dim machineNum As String

LastRow = Sht2.Range("E" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
Lastrow2 = Sht2.Range("E" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value
machineNum = Sht3.Cells(E1).Value

If (machineNum = Sht2.Cells(I1)) Then
Sht3.Range("I2:I13").Copy
Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

If (Lastrow2 = "") Then
Sht3.Range("J2:J13").Copy
Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


Next i
LastRow = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row
Lastrow2 = Sht2.Range("A" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Row

If (LastRow = Lastrow2) Then

Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "12 rows from sheet1 to sheet2" - is there any way you could include an example?

Comment: In sheet 1 I have 12 rows of data called max score so for example I have a machine number M03 as column hearder  and it has 12 rows of max scores say 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 and I have M04 as column header in same sheet 1 and the scores will be 2,3,5,4,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,11 so in sheet 2 I have a header Machine number and the rows contain the machine number so what I need is machine number from sheet 2 has to check machine number from sheet 1 and display those 12 scores in sheet 2. Ex: Sheet 2 machine number has to check M03 from sheet 1 and paste all the max scores in machine number sheet 2

Comment: What have you tried? A screenshot would be more useful what with a picture being worth 1000 words.

Comment: Sub Chapters_Practical()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim i, j  As IntegerDim LastBlankRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set Sht3 = Worksheets("Chapters")
Set Sht2 = Worksheets("Practical results")

Comment: If (Sht2.Range(E1)) = "M03" Then
Sht3.Range("I2:I13").Copy
Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ElseIf (Sht2.Range(E1)) = "M04" Then
Sht3.Range("J2:J13").Copy
Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

Comment: I'm confused... You say you want to copy from `sheet 1` to `sheet 2` - but your code appears to be dealing with `sheet 2` and `sheet 3`. Which sheets are you dealing with?

Comment: Sorry I mentioned them as as example as sheet 1 and sheet 2 but in reality they are sht 2 and sht 3 just a name difference

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code as it stands? For one thing it should be `Range("E1")`.

Comment: If my answer works, please mark it as complete. Otherwise, comment with why it's not working for you

Comment: Any ideas for second code is appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think this should do the trick...

```
Public Sub TransferData()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Chapters") ' I'm assuming this is "Sheet 1"
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Practical results") ' I'm assuming this is "Sheet 2"

    Dim k As Range
    Dim lastCol1 As Integer
    Dim lastCol2 As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim r As Integer


    lastCol1 = ws1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    lastCol2 = ws2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    For i = 1 To lastCol1
        Dim machineNum As String
        machineNum = ws1.Cells(1, i).Value
        For j = 1 To lastCol2
            ' If they match, then print
            If ws2.Cells(1, j).Value = machineNum Then
                For r = 2 To 13 ' I am assuming you have one header row, 12 data rows
                    Set k = ws1.Cells(r, i)
                    ws2.Cells(r, j).Value = k.Value
                Next r
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Arod, I tried executing your code by changing the sheet names the way I needed, the code is running but I don't get any data in the sheet. can I know what this line here does machineNum = ws1.Cells(1, i).Value

Comment: `machineNum=ws1.Cells(1,i).Value` gets the machine number from the first worksheet

Comment: Hi Arod, Thank you for your efforts, I tried to work with the code but I don't get any output out of the code which you have provided.

Comment: Do you know how to place a breakpoint? If so, put one on the line that says `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` and then step through it. Debugging commands can be found in the toolbar under `Debug`